# Running out of memory whenever trying to draft an email at gmail from Edge

Tags: windows-7, out-of-memory, microsoft-edge

I have been using my antique pc with a bit of stress at times and full of gratefulness at other times, but starting from yesterday, my old pc began stressing me out, and, most importantly, I couldn't fix it just by following a few tutorials on the internet.

Yesterday, when I wanted to draft some emails on Gmail from MS Edge, which I have been using since it is considered the most RAM-friendly, it crashed, and the crash continued no matter how many times I refreshed the page or restarted the pc. `It says the error code: Out of memory`

Sure enough, opening the task manager tab, I saw that MS Edge was using about 3000000k or 300 Mb, and it also displayed roughly 90% of memory was being used when the Gmail tab is only open and no other activity was going on. For a different person, the result may seem obvious, but my pc has been working somewhat ok, at least it wouldn't crash for just opening a Gmail tab and drafting an email. Therefore, it is not a normal occurrence from my perspective.

Do you know what is the strangest thing? My PC's performance has gotten better; for example, while asking this question, nothing happened, and it is responding extremely quickly as if I am working on the latest laptop haha. Then, what happens when entering Gmail?

Ok, here are a few pictures that may be useful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Windows 7 OS is out of support. Further, your machine has 1 GB RAM which is pretty low. I would suggest try updating the MS Edge browser to the latest version and see whether it helps you fix the issue. If not, I suggest you upgrade your machine hardware and install the supported OS. It might help avoid this kind of issue.

Comment: It could be possible that the Gmail site tab consumes more memory. Due to the limited size of the memory, The Edge browser is not able to load the web page successfully and shows you the error mentioned in the original post. If any other program is open then you could close them and then try to open Gmail in the Edge browser.